# Audio Equalizer Software in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack, equalizer

I want to install an audio equalizer in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS. Is there one I can use? I was going to install `pulseaudio-equalizer` but it does not work. Is there any way to install `pulseaudio` systemwide?

Comment: You can download and install the package from the WebUpd8 PPA Link: https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=pulse&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial Info found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/689969/what-are-the-options-for-audio-equalizers-in-ubuntu-15-10

Answer (score 14):

This list is roughly sorted from *simple* to *professional* and of course far from being complete.

## Alsaequal

[image: Alsaequal]

Alsaequal is an equalizer plugin for the (usually preinstalled) command-line audio mixer `alsamixer` as well as `amixer`.

### Installation

```
sudo apt install libasound2-plugin-equal
```

### Start

```
alsamixer -D equal
amixer -D equal
```

To change to the equalizer in the running program, press <kbd>F6</kbd>, choose `enter device name...` and enter “equal”.

### Configuration

You can find [configuration tipps on wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture#System-wide_equalizer), e. g. how to save and load custom presets.

---

## PulseAudio Equalizer

[image: PulseAudio Equalizer]

### Installation

#### Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty and 16.04 Xenial

Follow [these instructions on webupd8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/system-wide-pulseaudio-equalizer.html).

#### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

### Start

```
qpaeq
```

If you encounter an error and are told to `make sure you have the pulseaudio dbus module loaded` follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/982556/507051).

---

## JackEQ

[image: JackEQ]

### Installation

```
sudo apt install jackeq
```

### Requirements

JackEQ needs a configured and running **JACK Audio Connection Kit**, a howto is provided by [this article on libremusicproduction.com](http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/demystifying-jack-%E2%80%93-beginners-guide-getting-started-jack).

---

## JAMin

[image: JAMin]

JAMin is the JACK Audio Connection Kit (JACK) Audio Mastering interface (…) designed to perform professional audio mastering of stereo input streams. <sup>[source](http://jamin.sourceforge.net/en/about.html)</sup>

### Installation

```
sudo apt install jamin
```

### Requirements

JAMin needs a configured and running JACK, a howto is provided by [this article on libremusicproduction.com](http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/demystifying-jack-%E2%80%93-beginners-guide-getting-started-jack).

---

## JACK Rack with LADSPA effects

[image: JACK Rack]

JACK Rack is a sound studio rack where you can store and combine LADSPA effect plugins. A collection of plugins is contained in the `ubuntustudio-audio-plugins` package. More on [ladspa.org](http://www.ladspa.org).

### Installation

```
sudo apt install jack-rack
```

### Requirements

JACK Rack needs a configured and running JACK, a howto is provided by [this article on libremusicproduction.com](http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/demystifying-jack-%E2%80%93-beginners-guide-getting-started-jack).

---

Advanced audio software – normally using the JACK Audio Connection Kit – of course also comes with equalizing features. As I feel like this goes beyond the scope of this question, here's just a short list with links.

- [Kwave](http://kwave.sourceforge.net): `sudo apt install kwave`
- [MusE](http://www.muse-sequencer.org): `sudo apt install muse`
- [Audacity](http://www.audacity.de): `sudo apt install audacity`
- [LMMS](https://lmms.io): `sudo apt install lmms`
- [Rosegarden](http://rosegardenmusic.com): `sudo apt install rosegarden`
- [Ardour](http://ardour.org): `sudo apt install ardour`, needs plugins for equalizing features
- [Qtractor](http://qtractor.org): `sudo apt install qtractor`
- [Renoise](http://www.renoise.com)
- [ocenaudio](https://www.ocenaudio.com)

Further information about audio software can be found on the German Ubuntu wiki [wiki.ubuntuusers.de](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Tonstudio/).

Answer (score 3):

[PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects) provides a "limiter, compressor, reverberation, equalizer and auto volume effects for Pulseaudio applications":

[image]

According to the [installation instructions](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu), to install on Ubuntu >= 18.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio --install-recommends
```

An older version which should install on Ubuntu 16.04 is available in this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~yunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3/

Answer (score 0):

First install pulseaudio using apt (sudo apt-get install pulseaudio). Then set it as the default audio system where you set the default programs in Lubuntu (it will replace alsamixer) and then install pulseaudio-equlizer (sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer).