# How do I start pulseaudio-equalizer?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pulseaudio, 17.10

I just installed `pulseaudio-equalizer` on my Ubuntu 17.10 following the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer) with:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

When I want to start the application I get:

```
$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

How can I start `pulseaudio-equalizer`?

Comment: The canonical question for equalizer software in general is: [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/72679/507051)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To start the pulseaudio equalizer run:

```
qpaeq
```

If this gives you the error

```
There was an error connecting to pulseaudio,
please make sure you have the pulseaudio dbus module loaded, exiting...
```

then load these two modules using [`pactl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pactl.1.html):

```
pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink
pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

and, to make these changes permanent, edit `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` (create it if necessary) and add these lines:

```
load-module module-equalizer-sink
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

If you are a wayland user, start the equalizer this way instead:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland qpaeq
```

Comment: I get `27` as output from the first command and `Failure: Module initialization failed` for the second on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** I've created [a small setup script](https://gist.github.com/leogama/35961ec0d279e6cf409f783c3851569e) that creates all the three files and puts them in the right places. Just download the script and execute it in a terminal: `sh pulseaudio-equalizer-setup.sh`

---

If you only need/want the sound equalizer running while the equalizer GUI is open, I created a minimal working solution with these files:

`~/.config/pulse/default.pa` — make the dbus-protocol module load by default

```sh
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa

# Needed by module-equalizer-sink.
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

`~/.local/bin/equalizer` — must be made executable

```sh
#!/bin/sh
pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink
pactl set-default-sink "$(pactl list sinks short | awk '/equalizer/ { print $2 }')"
qpaeq
pactl unload-module module-equalizer-sink
```

`~/.local/share/applications/equalizer.desktop` — create icon in applications menu

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=PulseAudio Equalizer
GenericName=Sound Equalizer

Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=equalizer
TryExec=qpaeq
StartupWMClass=qpaeq

Icon=audio-headphones
Categories=Qt;AudioVideo;
```

**Note 1:** Make sure that `~/.local/bin` is in your `PATH`. Otherwise, either move the executable file to a directory that *is* in `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) or substitute the command in the `Exec=` entry by an absolute path to the script.

**Note 2:** To run the application immediately after installing the files to the correct places, run this command before:

```
$ pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

---

**Tip:** If you resize the equalizer's window, widening it, more controls appear for narrower audio frequency bands, allowing fine-grain tuning.

[image: PulseAudio Equalizer]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant to be in support of those already here. A great way to solve a problem like the one above is to type

```
apropos pulseaudio | grep \(1\)
```

and you should end up with a list of every command on your machine with the word pulseaudio anywhere in it's manual's description. Typing `man -k` has the same effect as `apropos`, but the latter is easier to remember, in my opinion.

Comment: To get the binaries associated to a package one of the easiest method is `dpkg -L pulseaudio-equalizer | grep bin`