# Problem when launching pulseaudio-equalizer

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I have installed `pulseaudio-equalizer` in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Right after the installation, I got the error `There was an error connecting to pulseadio, please make sure you have the pulseaudio dbus module loaded, exiting...`, which is solved in this related question [How do I start pulseaudio-equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980876/how-do-i-start-pulseaudio-equalizer/)

However, implementing the above solution, I now get the error
`Command 'qpaeg' not found, did you mean ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I use debian/openbox to prefer open source

cp /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/

insert following lines into ~/.config/pulse/

```
#
# solve "error connecting to pulseaudio..." after invoking qpaeq from package pulseaudio-equalizer
#
load-module module-equalizer-sink
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

restart pulse audio via

```
$ pulseaudio --kill
$ pulseaudio --start
```

Then I used pavucontrol and chose "FFT based equalizer on ..." in the Playback tab as the desired output for the desired program playing music. I would prefer to use pactl to perform the task so that I can create an equalizer on/off keystroke.

Pulseaudio should save the chosen state for each program in ~/.config/pulse/.

Cooloutac on wiki gitlab says that if you have static and crackling when using the qpaeq, then you must append for modify existing udev module line to read

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Don't forget to restart pulseaudio with every change to default.pa.

Comment: Rather than copying the system-wide `/etc` config, just start the one in your home dir with `.include /etc/pulse/default.pa` This way, any system wide changes in future versions will automatically propagate to the user.