# qpaeq no module named dbus

Tags: pulseaudio, dbus

NOTE: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980876/how-do-i-start-pulseaudio-equalizer) is not relevant to the `dbus` problem I am experiencing as described below.

I tried to run `qpaeq` after installing.  It asks for `dbus`.  Other posts say to install `python-dbus`.  It doesn't help. There is also no `dbus-python`, which is what `qpaeq` is asking for.  What to do?  Transcript follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pulseaudio-equalizer python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 50.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 281 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 amd64 5.14.1+dfsg-3build1 [16.8 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 pulseaudio-equalizer amd64 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7 [34.0 kB]
Fetched 50.7 kB in 0s (281 kB/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5.
(Reading database ... 475713 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5_5.14.1+dfsg-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio-equalizer.
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio-equalizer_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-equalizer (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-equalizer (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.7) ...

$ qpaeq
There was an error importing needed libraries
Make sure you have qt5 and dbus-python installed
The error that occurred was:
    No module named 'dbus'

$ sudo apt-get install python-dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dbus is already the newest version (1.2.16-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.

$ qpaeq
There was an error importing needed libraries
Make sure you have qt5 and dbus-python installed
The error that occurred was:
    No module named 'dbus'

$ sudo apt-get install dbus-python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dbus-python
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start pulseaudio-equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980876/how-do-i-start-pulseaudio-equalizer)

Comment: No, that answer isn't about the dbus error.

Comment: Please run the following commands in terminal :
`pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink

pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol`
then run it.

Comment: @kenn yeah that's what is missing, `module-dbus-protocol` . The message is not quiet clear about name. I tried in a virtualbox.

Comment: @kenn I just did both `pactl load`s and I still get the same error.  This is on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: I am also on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. I also had the same complaint you post above when I installed `qpaeq`. Loading those modules with `pactl` let me launch `qpaeq` without error.

Comment: Is `python3-dbus` installed?

Comment: @kenn, yes I did `sudo apt install python3-dbus` then `pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink` then `pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol` then `qpaeq` and I still get `No module named dbus`.

Answer (score 5):

If you get this error, you likely need a couple of modules, as noted in a comment above. If you want the changes to be permanent, you'll need to load the modules from `/etc/pulse/default.pa`. Add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
load-module module-equalizer-sink
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

You can trigger the changes to take effect immediately with `pulseaudio -k`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

For me it was caused by locally installed version of `pyqt5` which probably wasn't up to date (or missing something from the system packager provided one).

You can check this by doing this:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 20 2021, 18:40:11)
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus.mainloop; print(dbus.mainloop)
<module 'dbus.mainloop' from '[PATH]'>
```

If the value of `[PATH]` points somewhere into your home directory (eg. starts at `/home/...`) then you have pyqt5 installed locally and it **might** be good idea to remove it and **leave** there only the package manager installed one.

Remove it with (**without using** `sudo`) by issuing `pip uninstall pyqt5` (it will ask and show you where from you are removing the package, the `[PATH]` should match that).