# How to Calibrate a Microphone?

Tags: microphone, headset

I tried there different headsets. All create a different tone of my voice.

Is there a way to calibrate the microphone?

Google gave me no results (or I used the wrong terms)

Comment: Maybe is a hardware issue related to the quality of your microphones. What magnitude do you want to calibrate? Do you mean to equalize it? Maybe [this](https://github.com/Zigazou/micro-equalizer) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772543/audio-equalizer-software-in-ubuntu-16-04) could help you. Maybe with OBS as the input.

Comment: @PabloBianchi it is not a broken sound. It is just a bit strange. That's why I want to calibrate it. My second headset has a sound, which sounds more real to me.

Comment: I didn't talk about a broken sound. Exactly what do you want to calibrate? Did you try those software? Also could try [PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu). This seems a hardware issue and therefore out of the scope of this site.

Comment: The question is not clear. Possibly useful: upload 3 sample sound tracks so one can understand what you mean.
Did you try the three same microphones in a different system (Win/Linux/Android), and they sound more similar to each other?
Samples of those 3 other tests also help.
Otherwise, it is virtually impossible to provide any help.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I don't understand why a sound sample would help here. It just does sound like speaking through the fog. And the other sound sample sounds like not speaking through the fog. OK, what is the next step after providing such samples?

Comment: I wouldn't be sure if sound samples *will* help, but they *might* help... it depends on what is there, among other things.
Besides, did you test what I suggested? You may provide details on that.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio no, I did not test what you suggested. Imagine I test the device on android. Now I realize: case1 "the sound is better", case2 "the sound is worse", case3 "the sound is the same". And now. What is the next step?

Comment: I wouldn't go through a full diagnosis flowchart. I am suggesting actions that, depending on the result, *might* help.
You may consider them potentially useful and carry them out, or not.

Comment: Plus, the test I proposed would likely indicate whether Ubuntu has a particular issue with the microphones, or it is the quality of the microphones themselves what produces the difference.
This would, of course, not answer the question of What-to-do-if.
I am simply suggesting ways you can help others help you.

Comment: Sound quality is about frequency response/distortion/noise...etc.  You can alter it by Equalizer/DSP/digital filters, but there's no calibration thing.  And I think the better place to discuss audio recording quality tuning is DAW software forum.