# "cannot open mixer: No such file or directory" when trying to run alsamixer to unmute after installing Realtek audio driver

Tags: unity, sound, alsa, soundcard, mute

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 5568 15", but the sound quality is lower than the one on the Windows session.

Then I searched for a solution and I downloaded [Rt-linux-HDaudio-5.18 from Realtek here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)

I did the steps written in the `readme.txt` inside :

Step 1. unzip source code

```
    tar xfvj alsa-driver-1.0.xx.tar.bz2
```

Step 2. Complied source code

```
cd alsa-driver-1.0.xx
./configure --with-cards=hda-intel
make
make install
```

Step 3. reboot your machine

Step 4. Use the alsamixer to disable mute (All audio line default is mute) excute alsamixer

The problem is, when I restarted my computer I found that the sound was disabled  and I couldn't run  alsamixer in terminal to fix it as they said in step 4. I get this error :

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

[image: this picture could give additional information]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This driver is outdated , uninstall it running `cd alsa-driver-1.0.xx` then  `make uninstall` , reboot and hope uninstall works fine and you get the previous driver.
- Sound is sometimes better in Windows because driver includes a builtin (and hidden) sound enhancer suitable for very small laptop loudspeaker  : you can have a not-so-bad  similar effect using **Pulseaudio equalizer** , see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689969/what-are-the-options-for-audio-equalizers-in-ubuntu-15-10)